# webpack return 'yargs.parse(process.argv.slice(2), (err, argv, output) =>' when running with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webpack

I have my app build with npm and webpack, it gives me following error.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:152
yargs.parse(process.argv.slice(2), (err, argv, output) => {
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

I have tried by updating my node version, npm but still it gives me the same error.
I am running it on my Virtual machine with Vagrant on windows.

Comment: what is `yargs`?

Comment: Also, please post the output of `node --version` in your question

Comment: What version of webpack is this that you are running. Also yargs is what webpack uses in our bin/webpack.js file to collect arguments from the CLI and convert them into config options.